# gradle error importing a .jar file with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, jar, gradle, import

I found the following error when I tried to add a .jar file in my project:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':android:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I'm pretty much sure the error is related to this portion of code in my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'AdBuddiz-AdMob-Java-3.0.14.jar')
}
```

But I can not delete one of these lines cause obviously I need this .jar library. I guess it happens because I already have some file from this .jar in my google-play-service libs but I'm not sure about that and still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: This error happens from compiling the same jar file twice.. so I'm assuming it involves AdBuddiz, or another jar in your libs folder. Remove jars and replace to see if it works?? what files are in your libs folder?

Comment: How many libs are you including ?
The same error message will also appear if you exceed the 65k method limit.
To get a better and more informationg error message you should build your project from command line with : gradlew.bat assemble

Comment: I only have libgdx jars in /libs/libgdx and this one in /libs! I think something in the jar is duplicated and something else doesn't. Could it be? Cause I never added this same jar before!

Comment: Moreover I tried compiling by terminal and that is the error I get:
"Execution failed for task ':android:compileDebugJava'.
> Could not find tools.jar"